# Winform with WPF Richtextbox - Disappearing Text

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a windows form with a WPF Richtextbox, and occasionally when copy and pasting the text part of it will disappear, but if you move the scroll bar up or down the text reappears.

Any ideas on what could the issue be?

Thanks!

Comment: show some code what are you trying and issue?

Comment: Have you checked the events for the textbox? Such as the MouseEnter event for example. Have you run your code in debug to test what's happening?

Comment: Try reducing the code to the minimum necessary to recreate the problem then if the problem is not obvious post the small sample. That sounds like a lot of work but I have done it myself, it is not something I am suggesting just because it is easy to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a TextBox fixed the issue.